# Finding extremal of function $J(x,y,y')=\int\left[y'(x)\right]^{2} + 12x\,y\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations

Find a curve passing through $\left(0,0\right)$ and $\left(1,1\right)$ that is an extremal for the functional
$\displaystyle{{\rm J}\left(x,y,y'\right)
=
\int\left\{\left[y'(x)\right]^{2} + 12x\,y\left(x\right)\right\}\,{\rm d}x}$

Hey, I'm not sure how to start this problem.. help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation

Comment: This post seems similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105129/to-find-an-extremal-of-the-functional-int-01-y2-12-xy-dx?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$$
0 = \delta{\rm J} = \int\braces{2y'\delta y' + 12 x\delta y}\,\dd x
=
\int\braces{\totald{\pars{2y'\delta y}}{x} - \delta y\bracks{2y'' - 12 x}}\,\dd x
$$
$$
2y'' - 12 x = 0\quad\imp\quad y\pars{x} = x^{3} + Ax + B
$$
With $y\pars{0} = 0$ and $y\pars{1} = 1$ we get $A = B = 0$. Then
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large y\pars{x} = x^{3}}
$$

Comment: thanks. I looked over the euler equation link, and your solution helps me understand a lot now!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it was Euler-Lagrange stuff.